# Extjs 4 make grid column headers non-selectable

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am having an issue where after sorting by a column in a `Ext.grid.Panel`, the column header remains highlighted. It looks the same way that it does when you hover over it. Is there a way to make it non-selectable i.e. it can be highlighted on mouseover, but clicking on it doesn't change its color?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update the `x-column-header-sort-ASC` and `x-column-header-sort-DESC` CSS classes, setting the background and border colors to whatever you want them to be.